# Plot a numerical integration as a function of a variable

Tags: numerical-integration, vector, list-manipulation

Suppose we have a function that is hard to evaluate analytically but a numerical estimate suffices. For example consider the $f(x,\Lambda) = \Lambda\cdot \sin(x)$ where $\Lambda$ is some parameter I want to be able to play around with after after/before the integration. How can one tell mathematica to "`NIntegrate`" $f(x)$ and then plot the solution as a function of $\Lambda$? In Matlab I let e.g. $\Lambda$ be a vector ranging (say) from 0 to 1 and then do the integral for each value of $\Lambda$ and save that in a vector of similar length as $\Lambda$. What is the corresponding operation in Mathematica?

Comment: For your trivial example this works and is equivalent to the described behavior of Matlab: `Plot[NIntegrate[y Sin[x], {x, 0, 1}], {y, 0, 1}]`. What `Plot` does here, is assign a numerical value to `y` and then evaluate its argument (`NIntegrate`). It does that for several points in the range of `{0, 1}`. While this is fine for a simple integral like yours, some integrals may be horribly time consuming.

Comment: How can one set the interval of y to (say) 50 points or n points more general?

Comment: There are different approaches. In the case of `Plot`, by default it is adaptive. If it detects some nonlinearities in the resulting function it may increase the number of sampled points in the relevant region. You can control this by using `Plot[..., PlotPoints->50, MaxRecursion->0]` which will just sample 50 evenly spaced points and no recursion will prevent it from looking closer at any given point.

Comment: How can one save the result in an array before plotting, so as to not having to `NIntegrate` again in case one wants to plot again in the future.

Comment: Check the documentation of `Array` and `Table`. Having saved a table of pairs you will no longer be able to put that into `Plot` (it's for plotting functions), but will need `ListPlot` (for plotting sampled data) instead.

Comment: OK. Thanks you have in principle answered my question. Cheers¨

Answer (score 2):

```
y1 = 0; y2 = 1;
n = 50;
y = Range[y1,y2, (y2-y1)/(n-1.)];
f[x_, y_] := y Sin[x]
```

If your function is `Listable` you can do this

```
points = {y, NIntegrate[f[x, y], {x, 0, Pi}]} // Transpose;
ListLinePlot[points]
```

If your function is not `Listable`:

```
points = Map[{#, NIntegrate[f[x, #], {x, 0, Pi}]} &, y]
ListLinePlot[points]
```

[image]